# How do I insert data from a select and a variable?

Tags: postgresql, sql-insert, plpgsql

I have a variable, say `insert_reply_to_uid`;

I want to insert into a table values from a `SELECT` statement as well as the value of the variable.

A sample code, which is giving run time errors is:

```sql
INSERT into "chats" (uid, dated, chatdata, replytouid)
VALUES (
  (select * from json_populate_record(null::chats_table_type, rec)),
  @insert_reply_to_uid
)
RETURNING id into ids;
```

The first three values come from the `select * from json...` and the fourth is the variable.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming this happens inside a PL/pgSQL code block, since you tagged [plpgsql](/questions/tagged/plpgsql), there are no "variables" in plain SQL, and you are returning `INTO` a result variable, which is a feature of PL/pgSQL, not available in plain SQL.

PL/pgSQL variables are [identifiers](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-IDENTIFIERS) that cannot start with `@`. Assuming the legal name you implied at the top: `insert_reply_to_uid`.

This would work:

```sql
INSERT INTO chats
        (uid,   dated,   chatdata, replytouid)  -- optional pretty format
SELECT i.uid, i.dated, i.chatdata, _insert_reply_to_uid
FROM   json_populate_record(NULL::chats_table_type, rec) i
RETURNING chats.id INTO ids;
```

You don't need another `VALUES` wrapper around the `SELECT`, just add the variable to the `SELECT` list.
If the `SELECT` could return "no row", this could make a difference, but `json_populate_record()` always returns exactly one row.